# Replace Floating point numbers in a list with '0'

Tags: python, python-3.x

So my programming assignment wants me to take a user inputted list of numbers, ints and floating, and then order them in descending order and replace any of the floating with "0". I have got the reorder part done but the replace is getting me lost.

Reading Numbers
Write a program that shall ask the user to enter several integer numbers on
the same line, separated by vertical bars surrounded by zero or more spaces
(e.g., “|” or “ |” or “| ” or “ | ”). The program then shall display the entered
numbers in the descending sorted order (from the largest to the smallest),
all on the same line, separated by vertical bars and spaces (“ | ”). If
any entry on the command line is not an integer number, the program shall
replace it with a 0. Use only “for” loop(s) or list comprehensions. Use exception
handling.

```
# takes input and split them to get a list
numbers = input("Please enter numbers separated by vertical bars '|' : 
").split("|")
# replace the floating numbers with "0"
for number in numbers:
    print(type(number))
    if number.isdigit() == False:
        numbers.replace(number,'0')
# takes the list and reverse order sort and prints it with a "|" in between
numbers.sort(key = float , reverse = True)
[print(number,end = ' | ') for number in numbers]
```

Comment: `type(number)` is *never* going to be `float`, because `number` is a string!

Comment: @MarkRansom oh yeah i forgot to change that but i took that out

Comment: And the code you have now runs without any obvious errors?

Comment: @MarkRansom no problem errors that shows in the console, it just that the replace with 0 part doesnt works even doe the compiler reads it

Comment: Then you need to double-check that the code you're running is identical to the code that you posted. What I see here would generate obvious errors.

Comment: @MarkRansom Wher is the errors? I copied and pasted the code

Comment: `numbers.replace(number,'0')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One change I made was switching all of the `for number in numbers` to `for i in range(len(numbers))`.  This allows you to access the actual variable by index, while `for number in numbers` just gets the value.

Here is my solution.  I tried to add comments to explain why I did what I did, but if you have any questions, leave a comment:

```
# takes input and split them to get a list
numbers = input("Please enter numbers separated by vertical bars '|'\n").split(
    "|")

# strip any extra spaces off the numbers
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    numbers[i] = numbers[i].strip(" ")

# replace the floating numbers and strings with "0"
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    try:
        # check if the number is an int and changes it if it is
        numbers[i] = int(numbers[i])
    except:
        # set the item to 0 if it can't be converted to a number
        numbers[i] = 0

# takes the list and reverse order sort and prints it with a "|" in between
numbers.sort(reverse = True)

# changes the numbers back into strings
numbers = [str(numbers[i]) for i in range(len(numbers))]
# makes sure that there are more than one numbers before trying
# to join the list back together
if len(numbers) > 1:
    print(" | ".join(numbers))
else:
    print(numbers[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

the instructions permit you to use exceptions.  the following should get you most of the way there.

```
>>> numbers = ['1', '1.5', 'dog', '2', '2.0']
>>> for number in numbers:
>>>    try:
>>>        x = int(number)
>>>    except:
>>>        x  = 0
>>>    print(x)
1
0
0
2
0
```

Comment: i need to replace the one i the list as well

Comment: what 'i' ?  the numbers list i used has the digit 1 (one)

Comment: sorry in* basically it needs to replace the floating point number in the list with a 0 and then print the list

Comment: i've given you 95 % of the solution.  try it and show me your output

Comment: Please enter numbers separated by vertical bars '|' : 10.2|20|2|5|4|1|99|9|7
99
20
0
9
7
5
4
2
1
99 | 20 | 10.2 | 9 | 7 | 5 | 4 | 2 | 1 |

Comment: `numbers = input("Please enter numbers separated by vertical bars '|' : 
    ").split("|")
    numbers.sort(key = float , reverse = True)

    for number in numbers:
        try:
            x = int(number)
        except:
            x  = 0
        number.replace(number,str(x))
    
    [print(number,end = ' | ') for number in numbers]`